# using setInterval in socket.emit

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Hi I would like to ask if I am in the right direction.on using setInterval to update records in database and to get newly added records in database. my question for this is this will not cause performance issue ?

```
setInterval(function () {

        socket.emit('drawmarker', {devid: thearray, logid: logid});

}, 1000);

setInterval(function () {

    socket.emit('displayupdate', {devid: thearray, logid: logid});

}, 1000);

setInterval(function () {

    socket.emit('getmessages', {logid: logid});

}, 1000);

setInterval(function () {

    socket.emit('requestconvert');

}, 3000);
```

Comment: What kind of performance issue?

Comment: @zkerms, for example below on my setinterval I have jquery events that will click element of table. my question for this, does the setInterval will not block if I click table rows ? or the click event will trigger even my setInterval is running ?

Comment: There is nothing time consuming in code provided. But, there is a broader problem: you're making performance assumptions instead of measuring. Performance optimisation must **ALWAYS** be preceded by reliable profiling. And you optimise **ONLY AFTER** you have "scientifically" proven you're optimising the "right" part.

Comment: @zerkms, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them all three in the same interval? 
You can also add a simple counter and put them all in the same 1000ms interval and just only send "requestconvert" on every 3000ms

```
setInterval(function () {

socket.emit('drawmarker', {devid: thearray, logid: logid});

socket.emit('displayupdate', {devid: thearray, logid: logid});

socket.emit('getmessages', {logid: logid});

}, 1000);

setInterval(function () {

socket.emit('requestconvert');

}, 3000);
```

*Edit:* Your concerns about performance issues, it would highly depend on what they acually do.